# Syslogd kernel:code:

Tags: fedora, java, crash, kernel

While running some experimental Java code which interacts with a MySQL server, I received these messages and then the server crashed:

```
Message from syslogd@localhost at Jun 20 20:04:12 ...
 kernel:Stack:

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jun 20 20:04:12 ...
 kernel:Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jun 20 20:04:12 ...
 kernel:Code: e0 48 8d 55 b0 48 89 4d e8 4c 89 45 f0 48 89 45 b8 48 8d 45 d0 4c 89 4d f8 c7 45 b0 10 00 00 00 48 89 45 c0 e8 5a ff ff ff c9 c3 <89> f0 b9 40 00 00 00 55 99 45 31 c0 f7 f9 48 89 e5 48 89 fa 41
```

What do they mean? After restart, everything is working again. /var/log/messages has no entries near the time of the event and dmesg doesn't seem to show anything about it either.

Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
2.6.34.8-68.fc13.x86_64